# Почему пишется "насчет" слитно?

Tags: предлоги

Если я правильно помню, правила гласят, что, если приставку можно разбить от корня другим словом, то это не приставка, а предлог. Берём: "насчет этого он сказал" и "на этот счет он сказал" означают одно и то же. То есть нет разных смыслов, контекстов и пр. Тогда почему при живом правиле "насчет" пишется слитно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как Розенталь правила придумывал

Он не то чтобы очень любил придумывать правила, ему приходилось этим заниматься в том случае, когда слово нельзя было написать по слуху, а приходилось выбирать: А или О, Е или И, слитно или раздельно. Чтобы сделать правильный выбор, Розенталь проводил грамматический анализ, а свое решение называл правилом. Когда он обосновывал и выбирал слитное написание, то все говорили: вот Розенталь правила придумывает. Если он выбирал раздельное написание, то говорили то же самое. Конечно, это  было несправедливо,  но он ничего не мог придумать, чтобы изменить всеобщее мнение.

Итак, правила слитного, раздельного и дефисного написания слов практически всегда являются следствием грамматического анализа. Вы можете выполнить такой анализ или запомнить его результат в виде правила - это ваш выбор.

А вот и сам анализ. Существуют два варианта написания: на счет - падежная форма существительного "счет" (положить деньги на счет) и насчет - производный предлог с изъяснительным значением (договориться насчет поездки), его можно заменить предлогом О.
Подстановка "на мой счет" только подтверждает факт падежного управления, можно также задать вопрос: на что? - на счет. В первом случае мы имеем реальное существительное "счет "с предметным значением, а во втором такого существительного (счет поездки) нет, речь идет о переносном значении слова "счет".

Comment: Спасибо, всё очень понятно.